# If you fire a negatively charged bullet horizontally, what is the direction of magnetic field that surrounds it?

Tags: magnetic-fields, field-theory

If you fire a negatively charged bullet horizontally and watch it recede away from you, what is the direction of magnetic field that surrounds it. Clockwise or counterclockwise?

I know that I should use my left hand because it's negatively charged. I'm to use my first hand rule right? Since there's no coil. My guess is that it's clockwise.

I really want to get my directions right.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [right hand grip rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Right_hand_grip_rule), the negative charge is moving away from you which means the current is towards you.  Your thumb should point to your nose, hence the magnetic field is anti-clockwise.

If you've learnt cross product, the $B$-field can be expressed as

$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r},t) \approx \frac{\mu_{0}}{4\pi} \frac{Q\mathbf{v\times r}}{(\mathbf{r-v}t)^{2}}$$

where $\dfrac{v^2}{c^2} <<1$